# OSx Terminal send zipped file to directory

Tags: command-line, macosx, zip

I would like to zip the contents of a flash drive using this terminal command:

```
zip -r archive_name.zip folder_to_compress
```

The problem is, the flash drive is almost full, so I would like to make a zipped copy of it, but save the zipped copy in another directory.

**Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?**
*If you down vote, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Comment: OSx? that isn't ubuntu. And your question has a off-topic close vote now. Please edit the title and remove reference to OSX, it will be on-topic then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zip -r /path/to/archive_name.zip folder_to_compress
```

will create the archive in the folder you specify. Use `~/archive_name.zip` to create it in your home directory.